# How to know if Bootstrap carousel is transitioned by a human?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working with Twitter Bootstrap 3.3's carousel.  I need to track if a human has transitioned the carousel.

I am attempting to do something like this:

```
$(".carousel").on('slide.bs.carousel', function(e) {
  // carousel was transitioned!
});
```

However, I cannot find any discernible difference between an automatic transition and a user invoked transition.

How do you know that a bootstrap carousel was transitioned by a user and not by the automatic timer?

Comment: Add an event listener for the button that the user clicks? (I assume that's what you mean by "transitioned by a user".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, that you are right and there is no differents in manual/auto sliding events. So solution may be to handle click event from carousel controls and do need logic here:

`$('#yourCarousel a.carousel-control').on('click', function (e) {
  console.log("slided manually!");
});`

Comment: Sidebar to this- how would you know which direction the carousel transitions?  On the event from slide.bs.carousel we have `e.direction`.

Comment: @Dylan, [here](https://codepen.io/raliev/pen/dgbgbM) you can see snippet with before-slide, after-slide and manual slide events working

Comment: May be there is better solution, but if we handle events from elements `a.carousel-control.left` / `a.carousel-control.right` — we know the direction of sliding. I've updated [snippet](https://codepen.io/raliev/pen/dgbgbM) for this purpose too. Hope this helps for your task